# How to send to a list of people by bcc in Gmail, but Salutation begin with their first names

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, email

In Gmail ---

How to: send to a list of people by bcc (blind carbon copy), but in the Salutation, writing

> Dear ...

with their first names.

For example, in

> Bcc: N1, N2, N3, ..., Nj, ...

The N1 in the 1st name on the list would receive his/her messages as:

> Dear N1,

The N1 in the 2nd name  on the list would receive his/her messages as:

> Dear N2,

The Nj in the jth name would receive his/her messages as:

> Dear Nj,

Comment: if you are personalizing the email with that persons name there is no need to use BCC or even CC. The email will only be sent to one person and they should be on the To: line

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this with Gmail/Google Sheets add-on called **[Mail Merge](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mail-merge-with-attachmen/nifmcbjailaccmombpjjpijjbfoicppp)** where you can create custom presets which can be further used like:

```
Dear {{First Name}},
```

> [image: 0]

---

Video tutorials:

- **https://youtu.be/F07Py7sraDg**
- **https://youtu.be/cWWrCsbCzUU** (Outlook)

Comment: thanks so much - I will check the video  +1